# Incorrect layout when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout

I have TextView in RelativeLayout, which works properly:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_client_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tv_label_client_out"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_label_client_in"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:ems="10" />
```

Now I need to place this TextView inside of ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/sv_client_in"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tv_label_client_out"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_label_client_in"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_client_in"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
         />

</ScrollView>
```

After this change layout looks OK (first image), but when keyboard is shown, it is corrupted (second image). How can I fix this?

[image: Good]

[image: Bad]

Full layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_label_client_host"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/label_host" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_client_host"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_label_client_host"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:inputType="text"
    android:lines="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_label_client_port"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_client_host"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/label_port" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_client_port"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_label_client_port"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:lines="1" />

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/sv_client_in"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tv_label_client_out"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_label_client_in"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_client_in"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
         />

</ScrollView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_client_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/btn_send"
    android:onClick="OnBtnSendClick" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_label_client_out"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_client_send"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/label_client_out" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_client_out"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_client_send"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:inputType="text"
    android:lines="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_client_clear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_client_port"
    android:text="@string/btn_client_clear"
    android:onClick="OnBtnClearClick"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_client_disconnect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_client_port"
    android:text="@string/btn_client_disconnect"
    android:onClick="OnBtnDisconnectClick" 
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_client_connect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_client_port"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_client_disconnect"
    android:text="@string/btn_client_connect"
    android:onClick="OnBtnConnectClick" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_label_client_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_client_connect"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/label_client_in"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you use the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" attirubte in your manifest?

Comment: @tomas: I tried both adjustResize and adjustPan, the same result.

Comment: And did you try without any attribute to the windowSoftInputMode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by using LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

This happens mainly because of the views aligning to bottom. You have aligned them to bottom, so when the keyboard pops up the bottom changes hence the Views associated with it.
Try checking your xml file.

Comment: What exactly should I change? This layout worked before adding ScrollView.